# GetSharedDefaultFolder auto adding shared calendar

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook, calendar

I have code to create appointments in another user's calendar.

When I call `.GetSharedDefaultFolder`of the `NameSpace` object it automatically adds an entry into the tree in Outlook under Shared Calendars in the format "Calendar - [user]" if that entry is not there.

How can I prevent it doing this as if you already have the users in the list as "[user]" you end up with a duplicate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eugene wrote [there](https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=8953), it was not possible to prevent `GetSharedFolder` to create a new folder.

But what you can do is to loop through all folders to remove the created folder.

As you said, these calendars are using a format : "Calendar - [user]". So what you can do (actually that's what I did), is to loop through all the `NavigationItems` and compare the found `.DisplayName` whith the "Calendar - [user]" format.
Then, you can use `.NavigationFolders.Remove(foundItem)` to remove the calendar from the view.

Here is my example:

```vb
    Dim navPane As Outlook.NavigationPane
    Dim navModule as Oulook.Module
    Dim navGroups As Outlook.NavigationGroups
    Dim naviGroup As Outlook.NavigationGroup
    Dim navigation_item As Outlook.NavigationItem


    navPane = Application.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane
    navModule = navPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(Outlook.OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleCalendar)
    navGroups = navModule.NavigationGroups
        i = 0
        j = 0
        l = 0
        For i = 1 To navGroups.count
            navigation_group = navGroups.Item(i)
            For j = 1 To navigation_group.NavigationFolders.count
                navigation_item = navigation_group.NavigationFolders.Item(j)
                If (Application.Session.CompareEntryIDs(navigation_item.Folder.EntryID, shared_fold.EntryID) = True) Then
                    navigation_folder_name = navigation_item.DisplayName
                    For l = 1 To navigation_group.NavigationFolders.count
                        navigation_item = navigation_group.NavigationFolders.Item(l)
                        If navigation_item.DisplayName = "Calendar - " & navigation_folder_name Then
                            'faire ici
                            navigation_group.NavigationFolders.Remove(navigation_item)
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

**The answer isn't complete yet, I will update as soon as possible.**